# Mismatched/wrong query parameters using notMatching and where

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I got a strange behaviour using the `notMatching` function of the query builder in combination with a standard `where`. The parameters given in `OR`/`AND` arrays seems to be mismatched (more precisely it seems to take the last one and use it for the pre-last one).

Here is my query:

```php
$myModel
->find('list')
->where(['column' => 'a value to match']) // If I remove the entire line it works
->notMatching('AnotherModel', function ($query) use ($value, $anotherValue) {
    return $query->where([
        'OR' => [
            ['secondColumn >=' => $value],
            ['secondColumn <=' => $value]
        ],
        'thirdColumn' => $anotherValue
    ]);
});
```

And here is the generated SQL (simplified):

```sql
`column` = `a value to match`
AND (
  `MyModel`.`id` NOT IN (
    SELECT 
      ...
    FROM 
      ... 
    WHERE 
      (
        (
          `secondColumn` >= $value 
          OR `secondColumn` <= $anotherValue /* The issue */
        ) 
        AND `thirdColumn` = $anotherValue
      )
  )
)
```

As you can see, `$anotherValue` is used instead of `$value`. If I remove the entire first `where` (after the `find`) it works as excepted. And interestingly I don't have the issue with `matching` or `innerJoinWith`.

Comment: What's your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`)? Also how are you checking the generated SQL (ideally check it in your DBMS logs)?

Comment: Exact version is CakePHP 3.8.11. And I'm checking the SQL using the CakePHP debug kit (version 3.22.4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in CakePHP version `3.8.12`